# Cmake looking for boost lib by full name instead of explicitly said short one

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, bamboo

I'm developing a project that uses boost compiled libraries. I want to run regression on Bamboo. My idea was to use boost from my system paths when im building on my pc, and a copied libboost_program_options.lib when building on bamboo. I copy boost headers and libboost_program_options so they are in CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR/boost folder. The library was compiled with --layout=system so the file name is libboost_program_options.lib.

This is how my cmake looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.4)
project (Project)

file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)

set (SOURCE_FILES main.cpp other.cpp)

if (WIN32)
    set (SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES} many_other_windows.cpp )
endif (WIN32)

if (UNIX)
        set (SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES} many_other_unix.cpp)
endif (UNIX)


set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

# This is a hint for find_package to look for boost libs / includes in this dirs but it doesnt work
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/boost)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/boost)

find_package(Boost 1.63.0 COMPONENTS program_options)

if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

else()
  include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
  link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/boost)
  if (WIN32)
      set(TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES libboost_program_options)
  endif (WIN32)
  if (UNIX)
      set(TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES libboost_program_options.a)
  endif (UNIX)
endif()


add_executable (Project ${SOURCE_FILES})


if (WIN32)
    set(TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ${TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES} shlwapi)
endif (WIN32)


target_link_libraries(Project ${TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES})
```

part of the visual studio project file

type path/project.vcxproj:

```
(...)
<AdditionalDependencies>kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;libboost_program_options.lib;shlwapi.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
(...)
```

And the invocation of linker

```
04-Apr-2017 17:58:28      D:\MIDDLEWARE\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\AS-CA-W64\Project\bin\Release\Project.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"D:/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AS-CA-W64/PostCompilator/boost" /LIBPATH:"D:/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AS-CA-W64/PostCompilator/boost/Release" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib libboost_program_options.lib shlwapi.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:"D:/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AS-CA-W64/Project/bin/Release/Project.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/AS-CA-W64/PostCompilator/bin/Release/Project.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 Project.dir\Release\main.obj

04-Apr-2017 17:58:28    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_64.lib' [D:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\AS-CA-W64\Project\build\Project\Project.vcxproj]
04-Apr-2017 17:58:28    Done Building Project "D:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\AS-CA-W64\Project\build\Project\Project.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Notice how in cmake the short name changed for a full name with compiler name and version.

Anyone knows how to make cmake find that library? 
Does anyone have any suggestion how I can do it better to make my project buildable on both my pc with boost in system paths as on bamboo where I want to copy the lib? Maybe someone has better idea how to integrate boost into my project on bamboo

Best regards

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting the program_options library name used was cached previously by CMAKE and it is just re-using that?

Comment: I'm doing force clean build when checking out my repo, so totally everything should be removed before next build. It is also running link.exe  with short name so I don't think so. I'm not very skilled with cmake tho

Comment: Looks like file `libboost_program_options.lib` refers to `libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_64.lib` somehow. It is definitely not a CMake who *transforms* the first filename to the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for it was that boost windows headers add some pragmas that auto-look for the .lib file auto-filling it's name. This is what caused cmake to look for full name of library "libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_64.lib". I solved this by adding:

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB) # disabling of auto filling boost libs names to versioned
```